# SQL function with replace statement returning with junk value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

Created simple function to remove few special character but it is returning with junk values:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRemoveInvalidChars] (@Temp VARCHAR(300))
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
BEGIN

   SELECT @Temp = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Temp, ',', ''), '.', '') /* removing , and .*/
   return @Temp;
END
```

Returning values are like below:

```
58,871,300.00   => 5.88713e+007
55,146,000.00   => 5.5146e+007
8,296,000.00    => 8.296e+006
```

**Important** to note that, the value i am passing can be  Varchar, decimal,int or float and because of that it is not working correctly.

Comment: Why you're using `set @Temp = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Temp);`? Do you just want to remove `'.'` and `','` from a string?

Comment: @Temp is can be a Varchar, decimal or float... we can remove that if needed

Comment: @Sami... yes i just want to remove those only. but future may come few more...

Comment: Nope, you already declare it as a varchar parameter.

Comment: Your function is fine. It must be how you are passing the value to the function. How is the function called ?

Comment: share your sample input which is not working..

Answer (score 1):

First, alter your function as (although your function is working just fine):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRemoveInvalidChars] (@Temp VARCHAR(300))
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Buff VARCHAR(300);
  SELECT @Buff = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Temp, ',', ''), '.', '');
  RETURN @Buff;
END
```

Then you can use it as

```
SELECT [dbo].[fnRemoveInvalidChars]('58,871,300.00')
UNION
SELECT [dbo].[fnRemoveInvalidChars]('55,146,000.00')
UNION
SELECT [dbo].[fnRemoveInvalidChars]('8,296,000.00');
```

The results is:

```
5514600000
5887130000
829600000
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3637a49e9af6c903c934e77c4e678193)**